# How can I put the button to center of the window using Kivy library?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am writing a mobile game in python through the Kivy library and i'm faced to problem. I want to put the button to center of the window, but whatever parameters I gave, it is still stayed in the lower left corner. I tried to using 'pos: ' instead of 'pos_hint: ', but I can't move it in anyway. Please help to solve this problem.(see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4de3s.jpg)).

.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config


Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1280')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')


class HangApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return background()
    

class background(Widget):
    pass    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HangApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
<background>
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'background.png'
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    Button:
        text: "press"
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
        pos_hint: {"x":.5, "top":.5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `background` class is a simple `Widget`, which does not honor the `pos_hint` attributes of its children. Those type of attributes are used by the `Layout` classes. Try changing:

```
class background(Widget):
    pass
```

to:

```
class background(FloatLayout):
    pass
```